# Algorithm for combination index in array

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I know how to compute the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) given n and k (and I use a library for that).
Now imagine you store all of those combinations inside an array. Each combination has an index. I don't actually need to store them in an array, but I need to know, if I were to store them, what the array index would be for each combination.

E.g. given an element of the C(n,k) set of possible combinations, I need a function that gives me its index i inside the array, withtout actually creating the whole array. The programming language does not matter, though I need to implement the function in java, but any (pseudo-)language algorithm will do, I will then translate it to java.

For example, in the case of n=5 and k=2, I empirically define this function `f(n, k, [a,b]) => N` as:

```
f(5, 2, [1,2]) = 0
f(5, 2, [1,3]) = 1
f(5, 2, [1,4]) = 2
f(5, 2, [1,5]) = 3
f(5, 2, [2,3]) = 4
f(5, 2, [2,4]) = 5
f(5, 2, [2,5]) = 6
f(5, 2, [3,4]) = 7
f(5, 2, [3,5]) = 8
f(5, 2, [4,5]) = 9
```

meaning that the (3,5) combination would occupy index 8 in the array. Another example with n=5 and k=3 is `f(n, k, [a,b,c]) => N`, empirically defined as

```
f(5, 3, [1,2,3]) = 0
f(5, 3, [1,2,4]) = 1
f(5, 3, [1,2,5]) = 2
f(5, 3, [1,3,4]) = 3
f(5, 3, [1,3,5]) = 4
f(5, 3, [1,4,5]) = 5
f(5, 3, [2,3,4]) = 6
f(5, 3, [2,3,5]) = 7
f(5, 3, [2,4,5]) = 8
f(5, 3, [3,4,5]) = 9
```

EDIT for clarification after comments:

In the example above [1,2,3], [2,4,5] and so on, are one of the elements of the C(n,k) set, e.g. one of the possible combinations of k numbers out of n possible numbers. The function needs them in order to compute their index in the array.

However I need to write this function for generic values of n and k and without creating the array. Maybe such a function already exists in some combinatorial calculus library, but I don't even know how it would be called.

Comment: Hint: the number of array elements is `(n*(n-1)) /2`

Comment: @wildplasser no, I'm afraid it's not. The number of elements in the array is the binomial coefficient of n and k, e.g. n!/(k!(n-k)!)

Comment: You are talking about the *contents* of the array. I was talking about the array's *size* ( := number of elements), in your case (5*4/2) is 10.

Comment: No, I'm talking about array size too. 5*2 is also 10, but that does not mean the correct function is n*k.

Comment: Hint2: the index is the number of elements *before* it. (assuming base zero indexing)

Comment: @wildplasser so what? Sorry if I'm not that smart, but I don't get what you are suggesting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), the section "Place of a combination in the ordering" in particular.

There is even an example, which might help you: [National Lottery example in Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#National_Lottery_example_in_Excel). (I'm sorry, but I can't type any math in here.)

In your case this would be

```
f(5, 3, [2,3,4]) = binom(5,3) - 1 - binom(5-2,3) - binom(5-3,2) - binom(5-4,1) =
                 = 10 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 = 6
```

or if you accept a reversed order, you may omit the `binom(5,3) - 1` part and calculate

```
f'(5, 3, [2,3,4]) = binom(5-2,3) + binom(5-3,2) + binom(5-4,1) - 1 =
                  = 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 = 2
```

(This should save you some time, as `binom(5, 3)` is not really necessary here.)

In Java the method could be

```
int f(int n, int k, int[] vars) {
    int res = binom(n, k) - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        res -= binom(n - vars[i], k - i);
    }

    return res;
}
```

or

```
int fPrime(int n, int k, int[] vars) {
    int res = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        res += binom(n - vars[i], k - i);
    }

    return res;
}
```

assuming a method `int binom(int n, int k)` and `binom(n, k) = 0` for `n < k`.